# Integration Query for solving Bit error rate.

Tags: integration

How to solve this integral with complete steps?

[image: Inetgral query]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to evaluate

$$\int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^2 \, e^{-b y^2}$$

One simple way to do this is to consider

$$I(b) = \int_0^{\infty} dy \, e^{-b y^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} b^{-1/2}$$

The integral sought is therefore $-I'(b)$ which is

$$\int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^2 \, e^{-b y^2} = \frac14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b^3}}$$

Your integral, as written, is therefore

$$\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2 }} \frac14 \left (1+\mu u^2/2\right)^{-3/2}$$

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted.

Comment: [Part of a spree](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/apparent-systematic-downvoting-of-many-users). Unrelated, are you sure the exponent is $2$? I'm not sure whether it's $2$ or $r$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: thanks for the heads up.  I think it's $2$.  Not sure how you are reading an $r$, but maybe my eyes really are going.

Comment: I don't know what to read there. Could be a blurred version of one of the forms a handwritten $r$ has here, could be a very slanted and blurred $2$. I withhold judgment.